# Kotlin - Get all children recursively

Tags: kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin and trying to find best way to get all children in object.

I have this data class

```
data class BigObj(val id: Int, val text: String, val parentId: Int?, val children: ArrayList<BigObj>)
```

What I need is - get all possible objects from BigObj.children. Every children can have another list of children and I need them all. In C# I can do this one:

```
 foreach (var parent in source)
        {
            yield return parent;

            var children = selector(parent);
            foreach (var child in SelectRecursive(children, selector))
                yield return child;
        }
```

Does Kotlin has something similar?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html#from-chunks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin also have lazy collections processing implemented in [Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html).
There is no `SelectRecursive` function in stdlib, but you may define it yourself:

```kotlin
fun <T> Sequence<T>.selectRecursive(recursiveSelector: T.() -> Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> = flatMap {
    sequence {
        yield(it)
        yieldAll(it.recursiveSelector().selectRecursive(recursiveSelector))
    }
}
```

Now you may convert list (or any `Iterable`) of `BigObj`s to a desired flat sequence via simple:

```kotlin
val result: Sequence<BigObj> = source.asSequence().selectRecursive { children.asSequence() }
```

Comment: looks like it only goes to one level down. if child has its own children - code doesn't work.

Comment: Oops! Fixed it.